# dynamic memory allocation for char * holding integers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

When I am allocating memory dynamically to a char* pointer holding integer values, do I need to allocate one extra byte for the NULL termination always??

Example:

```
// usually obtained a variable value by reading the header information from a binary file
int nElements = 1000; 

// Do I need to allocate nElements+1 bytes here to hold a total of nElements integer values??
char* ptrData = new char[nElements];
```

Let us say I have opened a binary file and trying to read the data of that file as follows:
    //Read the data ranging from -127 to 0 from a binary file

```
int nElementsRead = fread(ptrData, sizeof(char), nElements,ptrFile);
// is the above operation OK or overflown by 1 byte to add/handle the NULL termination?


//Process the data 
int nInValidCount = 0;

for(int n=0; n< nElements; ++n)

if(ptrData[n] == 0) nInValidCount++; 
// do I have any problem here??

delete[] ptrData;
```

Is there any problem with accessing values or memory leaks or memory overflown?

In my actual code, the Data pointer has been passed across different functions and deleted in a separate function at the end.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Null Termination is for C-Style Strings. In your case you are reading
  n bytes from the file and hence allocating n bytes, So i see no need
  for extra byte.
- There is no memory leak a long as you make sure you free the
  memory which you have allocated.
- You say that the memory is freed in some other function , what if
  your program exits(because of an exception or logical exit) before
  reaching the function which frees the memory. In this case there will
  be a memory leak.
- Inside the for loop there is no problem

Answer (score 1):

To allocate memory for n chars you do:

```
char* c = new char[n];
```

This may contain the character of length up to `n`. If you want to use it with the `C-style` functions which depends on a `'\0'` this array might contain up to `n -1` char elements + terminating `'\0'` as the last element.

The `operator new` doesn't insert `'\0'`, you have to insert this by yourself, and `operator new [n]` allocates space for exactly `n` elements (if successful), not `n + 1`.

Comment: got it. Thanks. My question was, do I need to add space for extra NULL termination , while handling array of numbers unlike C-style strings..
Based on other answers, looks I don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

No. You do not have to in general. The only thing is that later when you try to, lets say, print the array of char, you have to already know how much size to print. Since you do not have a '\0' at the end, there is no other way to know what was the size of the char array stored without having been told the size. Same goes when trying to read.

Comment: Thanks..I am always making sure to read/write known exact size, as it is a part of the binary file header.

Answer (score 0):

`char* ptrData = new char[nElements];` will allocate you an array of `chars` of exactly `nElements` - no NUL termination is included. So if `nElements = 1000`, you'll get 1000 spaces for `char`.

If you want to manually append a `\0`, you'll need to do `char* ptrData = new char[nElements + 1];` and then set the `\0` at the last position yourself.

As for `fread`, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/ states:

> "The total amount of bytes read if successful is (size*count)."

So it will not append a `\0` or anything that it hasn't read from your file.